# How to change the background image in static cells on click programmatically?

Tags: swift, image, highlight, uitableview

1. Static cells.
2. An image on each cell.     Total - 10 images and 10 cells.
3. How to CHANGE image in cell or REMOVE it on cell click?

Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var menu1: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu2: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu3: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu4: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu5: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu6: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu7: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu8: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu9: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var menu10: UITableViewCell!

@IBOutlet var image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image9: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image10: UIImageView!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
```

1. Have a look which cell is pressed ... take an index
2. put this index -> "image"+[index] and remove it in image[index].image or change to other. ("didHighlight" in tableView function)?

   ```
       image1.image = UIImage (named: "menu_button_highlighted")
   }
   ```
3. how to set this back? ("didUnhighlight")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`tableView(_:​did​Select​Row​At:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) delegate method to respond to cell selection and update the image in the implementation​. Use the `indexPath` parameter to determine which cell was tapped.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //your logic here to change the background image
}
```

Also, consider creating an array of your image views for easy addressing and referencing using the index path.

```
let imageViews = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let imageViewToUpdate = imageViews[indexPath.row] //may need to adjust the array index to fit your table view configuration

    //your logic here to change the background image
}
```